# Matlab HeatMap color issue

Tags: matlab, heatmap

I am using *HeatMap* object which provides a HeatMap like the image below.

[image: Heatmap I created]

I am using this command:

```
hmo=HeatMap(data,'ColumnLabels',collabels,'ColorMap','copper','RowLabels',rowlabels,'ColumnLabelsRotate',45,'Symmetric',true,'Standardize','ROW');
```

However, I need the color scale (at the right) to be 0 to 1, and lightest color should represent the lowest value and vice versa.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the lightest colour represent lowest values you need to reverse the colormap order. You can do so by getting the colormap matrix and flipping it:

```
cmap = colormap('copper');
newcmap = flipud(cmap);
```

So instead of specifying the string 'copper' in the heat map call, you should pass *newcmap*.

To adjust the colorbar limits after the heat map creation, I believe you need to use the *CLim* option:

```
set(gca,'CLim', [0 1])
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Now, how can I set ticks on this heatmap?

Comment: This was not in the original question! But try set(gca,'XTick',firstvalue:interval:lastvalue). It is analogue to the Y axis, but you use the 'YTick' option instead. If you get fancy in your heatmaps give this submission a try: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24253-customizable-heat-maps . If the problem was successfully solved, please consider accepting it as an answer!

Comment: I was actually trying that. The command is executing, but no tick shown on the map.